# Progress Dialog Does Not Dismiss After Loading Webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Progress Dialog Does Not Dismiss After Loading Webview Is Goes On loading After Webview Is Loaded.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Progress Dialog", "Loading...");

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://kkgupta.mmiswebtech.com");



        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
        });
    }

     class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }





    @Override
    // This method is used to detect back button
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two calls to the method `webView.setWebViewClient();` (1) `webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());` and (2)  `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {..` ::  I'm thinking only one is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `onPageFinished()` to your `MyWebClient` and in it call `dismiss()` on your ProgressDialog:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I Have Done This But Not Working.Can you Edit It In Full code.@KT_

Comment: put this after `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` it should work

Answer (score 0):

use 
    `pd.dismiss();`

where u want ti dismiss Dialog.

Comment: Done This Not Working.                                                                                    @Override   
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Note: **ProgressDialog** is deprecated in API level 26. Better Use [**ProgressBar**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar)

**Delete this code**:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }

            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });
}
```

**change**:

```
 class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }
```

**To**:

```
class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    @Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { super.onPageFinished(view, url); if (pd.isShowing()) { pd.dismiss(); } }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }
```